# How to capture a cURL POST data and insert into db

Tags: php

I have this simple cURL POST code. How do i capture the data sent to 'test.php' and then insert it into a database with columns 'name' and 'age'.

Thanks

```
$url = 'http://localhost/public_html/member/api/test.php';

$ch = curl_init();

if($ch === false)
{
die('Failed to create curl object');
}

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post_data = array('name' => 'Harry', 'age' => '27');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code to run on test.php, to save the data send via post?

Comment: capture it where? in this script? or the `test.php` script?

Answer (score 1):

In test.php add the following..

```
 echo "I am here ";
 print_r($_POST);
```

In the above script do `print_r($output)` and it should show details of the response to your curl request which should include the echo from test.php and show you the contents of the $_POST array.

Then you can script your handler for the posted data in test.php and return something to your calling script to tell it if everything went OK